# Getting Metadata column field control on Custom form in sharepoint

Tags: managed-metadata, visual-web-part, taxonomy

I have a custom custom sharepoint form which i have created using visual webpart.

I want to have a Metadata field in my custom form.However, i am not able to find it in my ascx file.

Please help.

Comment: What you mean by have metadata field? You want the taxonomy selector control?

Answer (score 10):

a- Add reference to "Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" assembly

b- You need to register following Assembly in your Web Part

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

c- You can use the control as following

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl runat="server" ID="TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1"
   Visible="true" 
   IsDisplayPickerButton="true" <!--this will show the Picker Button near the textbox.-->
   IsMulti="true" <!--this will allow user to select Single or Multiple Terms.-->
   AllowFillIn="true" <!-- Allows user to add new terms.-->
   IsAddTerms="false" <!-- control will try to add unresolved Term objects to the TermSet object -->
   IsIncludePathData="false"> <!-- Includes Full Path of Term (Id of Group, TermSet & Term Itself) -->
</Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>
```

d- Now assign control to Managed Metadata.. You can use following code in PageLoad of Web Part:

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.SspId.Add(taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"].Id);
TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.SSPList = taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"].Id.ToString();
TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.TermSetId.Add(taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"].Groups["tGroup"].TermSets["tTermSet"].Id);
TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.TermSetList = taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"].Groups["tGroup"].TermSets["tTermSet"].Id.ToString();
```

- Use your own Group and Term Sets here

e- Get the values in code behind:

```
// this will contain the error message if the values are not correct.
string validationMessage;
var valid = TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.Validate(out validationMessage);

if (valid)
{
   var values = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(string.Empty);
   values.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.Text);
   foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue value in values)
   {
      var wssId = value.WssId; 
      var termGuid = value.TermGuid;
      var termlabel = value.Label
   }
}
else
{ 
   // display validation error message 
}
```

References:
[Add Taxonomy Field / TaxonomyWebTaggingControl to the Web part or Application Page](http://nipeshshah.blogspot.com/2012/04/add-taxonomy-field-taxonomywebtaggingco.html)
[Build Your Own User Interface Components Using The Taxonomy Controls](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/build-your-own-user-interface-components-using-the-taxonomy-controls/)

Comment: excellent explanation! +1

Comment: Good answer! Might be a good idea to add "e", how to get value from control after selection.

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg added "e" :)

Comment: Thanks, Nice one! what would lets say, TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.Text give me? Somthing like (label | guid)?

Comment: Label/GUID pairs that represent a Term object that is displayed in the control. [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.text.aspx)